# Why is operator overloading in Swift not declared inside the type it belongs to?

Tags: swift, operator-overloading

Why is operator overloading in Swift not declared inside the type it belongs to (like in C++) but in the global scope instead?

Comment: You would need to ask Apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Side note: Does it really matter?  That's how it is.*

The operators are not declared inside types because they are more akin or inline with global functions. Class methods and Structure functions typically **modify** or **query** the called entity.

In that sense  `let x = a + b` is more akin to writing `let x = add(a, b)` than it is `let x = a.add(b)` as the latter leads you to believe you're modifying the receiver (which is not true).

One could argue that you're querying it, in effect asking: *"A, if you were to be added to B, what would the result be"* but that's not a natural way to think of object/type interraction.

At the end of the day, it was a design decision.